# Disable the checkbox in "Prevent this page creating additional dialogs" ( Javascript alert )

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I implemented this function inside my asp.net project. Its working 100% working.

```
function barcodeValidation() {
var newbarcode, confirmBarcode;
newbarcode = document.getElementById("txtNewBarcode").value;
confirmbarcode = document.getElementById("txtConfirmBarcode").value;
if (newbarcode != confirmbarcode) {
        alert("Value not match");
        return false;
}
return true;
```

}

But the problem is when this window appearing for the 2nd time there is check box that saying "Prevent this page creating additional dialogs.... So how to disable this tick mark? If user put  tick mark to this, warning message will never display again.

Is there any method to workaround this?

Comment: the best way to prevent someone using the checkmark on that debug method is to never use alert().

Comment: @dandavis I agree.. Use an on page validation message.. alerts are extremely annoying to the user.